# How to change a do-while form loop into a while form loop in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

How can I change a loop in do-while form into a loop in while-form in LLVM IR?

Comment: do you want to do this on clang's AST or realy in the IR?

Comment: I want to do this in the IR.

Answer (score 3):

Here we have a little loop example. The loops are just running through a boolean array until they find the first occurrence of `true`. I compiled it with `clang -emit-llvm` to get the optimized llvm IR.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo(bool* start){
        bool* cond = start;;
        while (*cond != true)
                cond++;
        return cond - start;
}

int bar(bool* start){
        bool* cond = start;
        do {
        }while (*(++cond) != true);
        return cond - start;
}

int main(){
        bool cond[8];
        memset(&cond, 0, sizeof(bool)*8);
        cond[5] = true;
        printf("%i %i\n", foo(cond), bar(cond));
}
```

The IR for the foo function (using just a while loop) looks like this:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @_Z3fooPb(i8* %start) #0 {
  %1 = alloca i8*, align 8
  %cond = alloca i8*, align 8
  store i8* %start, i8** %1, align 8
  %2 = load i8** %1, align 8
  store i8* %2, i8** %cond, align 8
  br label %3

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %9, %0
  %4 = load i8** %cond, align 8
  %5 = load i8* %4, align 1
  %6 = trunc i8 %5 to i1
  %7 = zext i1 %6 to i32
  %8 = icmp ne i32 %7, 1
  br i1 %8, label %9, label %12

; <label>:9                                       ; preds = %3
  %10 = load i8** %cond, align 8
  %11 = getelementptr inbounds i8* %10, i32 1
  store i8* %11, i8** %cond, align 8
  br label %3

; <label>:12                                      ; preds = %3
  %13 = load i8** %cond, align 8
  %14 = load i8** %1, align 8
  %15 = ptrtoint i8* %13 to i64
  %16 = ptrtoint i8* %14 to i64
  %17 = sub i64 %15, %16
  %18 = trunc i64 %17 to i32
  ret i32 %18
}
```

and for bar, which is using a do while we get:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @_Z3barPb(i8* %start) #0 {
  %1 = alloca i8*, align 8
  %cond = alloca i8*, align 8
  store i8* %start, i8** %1, align 8
  %2 = load i8** %1, align 8
  store i8* %2, i8** %cond, align 8
  br label %3

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %4, %0
  br label %4

; <label>:4                                       ; preds = %3
  %5 = load i8** %cond, align 8
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds i8* %5, i32 1
  store i8* %6, i8** %cond, align 8
  %7 = load i8* %6, align 1
  %8 = trunc i8 %7 to i1
  %9 = zext i1 %8 to i32
  %10 = icmp ne i32 %9, 1
  br i1 %10, label %3, label %11

; <label>:11                                      ; preds = %4
  %12 = load i8** %cond, align 8
  %13 = load i8** %1, align 8
  %14 = ptrtoint i8* %12 to i64
  %15 = ptrtoint i8* %13 to i64
  %16 = sub i64 %14, %15
  %17 = trunc i64 %16 to i32
  ret i32 %17
}
```

The differences are very small for `bar` we have one additional label and an additional `br` because we jump strait to the body of the loop and execute it before we evaluate the condition.

So the first thing to transform a do while is to get rid of the branch and just jump to the condition. Now its a while loop where the condition is evaluated first. That is easy. Now you have two choices how you handle the condition. You can try to modify the condition what is a realy hard task because you can put almost everything inside a loops condition. The easy way is to just copy the loop body one time (everything from `;<label>:4` to `;<label>:11`) prior to the first branch of the loop. so you want change the correctness of your code and your do-while loop will become a loop (with on loop-body execution) in-front of the loop.

You can copy the loop body with `CloneBasicBlock` from `llvm/Transforms/Utils/Cloning.h`:

```
/// CloneBasicBlock - Return a copy of the specified basic block, but without
/// embedding the block into a particular function.  The block returned is an
/// exact copy of the specified basic block, without any remapping having been
/// performed.  Because of this, this is only suitable for applications where
/// the basic block will be inserted into the same function that it was cloned
/// from (loop unrolling would use this, for example).
///
/// Also, note that this function makes a direct copy of the basic block, and
/// can thus produce illegal LLVM code.  In particular, it will copy any PHI
/// nodes from the original block, even though there are no predecessors for the
/// newly cloned block (thus, phi nodes will have to be updated).  Also, this
/// block will branch to the old successors of the original block: these
/// successors will have to have any PHI nodes updated to account for the new
/// incoming edges.
///
/// The correlation between instructions in the source and result basic blocks
/// is recorded in the VMap map.
///
/// If you have a particular suffix you'd like to use to add to any cloned
/// names, specify it as the optional third parameter.
///
/// If you would like the basic block to be auto-inserted into the end of a
/// function, you can specify it as the optional fourth parameter.
///
/// If you would like to collect additional information about the cloned
/// function, you can specify a ClonedCodeInfo object with the optional fifth
/// parameter.
///
BasicBlock *CloneBasicBlock(const BasicBlock *BB,
                            ValueToValueMapTy &VMap,
                            const Twine &NameSuffix = "", Function *F = nullptr,
                            ClonedCodeInfo *CodeInfo = nullptr);
```

I hope this is a little help. Have Fun!

Comment: Thanks for answering. If the loop has multi-conditions, it would be a complex work , since llvm cannot answer whether the BasicBlock is belong to the loop conditions. In this case ,it's easier to do this on C/C++ source code. I have thought that there would be  APIs in clang or llvm could do this.